# What is the use of Hooks folder in Cucumber framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, hook

I am creating a selenium web driver and cucumber framework and had a look at a framework, where it has a folder for Hooks. But in general, we will have only one hooks file. So y do we need a hooks folder in automation framework?

Answer (score 0):

Hooks folder is totally optional, you can create couple hooks files.
For example `BeforeHooks.rb`, `AfterHooks.rb` and then create sub-directory in `support` and store hooks file there.